# Custom path border

Tags: c#, wpf, path, border

I want to create a border, that will also cover my `<Path>` caret object.

Here is what I have right now:

[image]

Here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

I have tried using `Path` stroke along with some hacky `StrokeDashArray` values, however, the result wasn't satisfying and it wasn't looking right.

**What is the other way to achieve a border around *whole* grid that will include the `Path`?**

Here is my current XAML code:

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Path
            x:Name="Caret"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="0,0,15,-1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Panel.ZIndex="1"
            Data="M0 10 L 20 10 L 10 0 Z"
            Fill="White" />

        <Border
            Grid.Row="1"
            Padding="10"
            Background="White"
            BorderBrush="Teal"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="15">
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You may consider a custom Shape, i.e. a class derived from Shape that overrides the DefiningGeometry property and the OnRenderSizeChanged method.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify your path Data and add stroke to your path to achieve what you are looking for. Give this code a try.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Path x:Name="Caret"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Margin="0,0,15,-1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Panel.ZIndex="1"
              Data="M0 10  L 10 0 L 20 10"
              Stroke="Teal"
              Fill="White" 
              ClipToBounds="True"
              />

        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                Padding="10"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Teal"
                BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="15">
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Like I said, I have tried this approach, but unfortunately, [this is not accurate](https://i.imgur.com/tfnvQwk.png)

Comment: You can use the ClipToBounds property to avoid the behaviour. Try the updated answer.

Comment: That would do the job, however the top corner [is also being clipped](https://i.imgur.com/S8QcuDt.png)